# Generate XML mapping of a recursive directory search

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

I am reading a list that has a large number of archives under certain components. 
e.g.

```
component1:filelocation1/a11.ear
component1:filelocation1/a12.ear
component2:filelocation2/a2.ear
component3:filelocation3/a3.ear
component4:filelocation3/basefile.properties
```

I need to unzip each archive recursively till the last level of data and generate an XML mapping file capturing the correct mapping from the component to the last element in the archive.

The xml document structure of which would be like:

```
<my-app>
    <mapping>
    <toplevel loc="filelocation1" filename="a11.ear" component="component1">
        <childlevel loc="." filename="x1.war">
          <childlevel loc="WEB-INF/classes" filename="abc1.class"/>
          <childlevel loc="WEB-INF/classes" filename="abc2.class"/>
        </childlevel>
    </toplevel> 
    <toplevel loc="filelocation1" filename="a12.ear" component="component1">
      <childlevel loc="." filename="x2.jar">
      <childlevel loc="org/test" filename="abc1.class"/>
      <childlevel loc="org/test" filename="abc2.class"/>
      </childlevel>
      <childlevel loc="." filename="x3.war">
          <childlevel loc="WEB-INF/lib" filename="web1.jar">
          <childlevel loc="org/test" filename="abc1.class"/>
      </childlevel>
      <childlevel loc="WEB-INF/classes" filename="abc2.class"/>
      </childlevel>
    </toplevel> 
    </mapping>
    </my-app>
```

What is the best appraoch to do that? I am considering using a DOM parser to generate the XML.

Comment: Just to add - the process involves reading the file list from a text file, unzipping each archive recursively, and while it is being unzipped building the XML mapping. So a recursive call to expant an archive would need somehow the parent element to be passed so that once it is out of the recursive loop we can have the right xml. This xml will have data for all archives in the text file we started with.

Comment: Do you have any preference for the language to use for the XML processing?

Comment: You can add the [tag:java] tag if it's related to your prior post.

Comment: I can not see any reason why the child node needs the parent. All you do is recursively writing directory listings for each archive. This can be done easily with every scripting language. [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) or [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) are a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Since JAR files are also ZIP files, if you are going to do this in Java, I would use the java.util.zip library.  Although you will still have to recursively open any JARs embedded in WARs and EARs, it will save you the trouble of stepping through the directories containing flat files.  You can also use the JarFile subclass of the ZipFile offered by the java.util.zip library.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html

I also probably wouldn't bother with a DOM parser for just printing out XML.  You'd be building a (potentially big) structure in memory when you could instead be printing data to a stream as you go.  Also, parsers are for parsing XML into a data structure, not vice versa.  The standard Java DOM parsing classes, javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory and javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder don't come with a "print" command.  The standard way to create formatted text output from a org.w3c.dom.Document object is to use an XSL transformer (See http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/xslt.html#gghkq) and again, that's probably more trouble than it's worth.  I suppose it depends on how much you want to extend this program, but if what you have here is all it has to do, I wouldn't build a big DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).

Gradle has nice built in facilities for unpacking archives. You can use groovy (comes with gradle) for XML parsing/generation, which will be a lot cleaner than using a Java XML library.